# How to force the display of every labels on yAxis in a BarChart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with `Highcharts`.

I want to display every `yAxis` labels, but by default `Highcharts` hide half my labels.

The height of the graphic is fixed and the number of categories is variable so increase the height is not a solution.

I have a trick to do it but I found it dirty :

I can add this in axis :

tickPositions: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]

but I try to find a better way.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rty3ohyz/1/) and my code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart : {
        type : "bar",
        backgroundColor : null,
        borderColor : "#000000",
        borderWidth : 0,
        options3d : {
            enabled : false
        }
    },
    plotOptions : {
        bar : {}

    },
    credits : {
        enabled : false
    },
    colors : ["#5B9BD5", "#ED7D31", "#A5A5A5", "#FFC000", "#70AD47", "#4472C4"],
    title : {
        align : "center",
        useHTML : true,
        text : ""
    },
    subtitle : {
        align : "center",
        useHTML : true,
        text : ""
    },
    legend : {
        align : "center",
        borderColor : "#000000",
        borderWidth : 0,
        enabled : false,
        floating : false,
        layout : "vertical",
        itemStyle : {
            color : "#000000",
            fontWeight : "normal",
            fontStyle : "normal",
            textDecoration : "none",
            fontFamily : "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
            fontSize : "11px"
        },
        shadow : false,
        verticalAlign : "bottom"
    },
    yAxis : {

        gridLineWidth : 1,
        gridLineColor : "#CECECE",
        labels : {
            enabled : true,
            style : {
                color : "#000000",
                fontWeight : "normal",
                fontStyle : "normal",
                textDecoration : "none",
                fontFamily : "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                fontSize : "11px"
            }
        },
        lineWidth : 0,
        title : {
            text : ""
        }
    },
    xAxis : {
        gridLineWidth : 0,
        gridLineColor : "#CECECE",
        labels : {
            enabled : true,
            style : {
                color : "#000000",
                fontWeight : "normal",
                fontStyle : "normal",
                textDecoration : "none",
                fontFamily : "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                fontSize : "11px"
            }
        },
        lineWidth : 1,
        title : {
            text : ""
        },
        tickLength : 10,
        categories : ["Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet,","consectetur","adipiscing","elit.","Etiam","sit","amet","vulputate","erat.","Ut","ultrices,","magna","luctus","elementum","hendrerit,","diam","erat","placerat","eros,","ac","sagittis"]
    },
    series : [{
            name : "etab",
            type : "bar",
            data : [2,10,11,29,56,3,10,40,6,25,28,17,19,7,27,7,14,46,20,49,3,13,3,31,12,13],
            dataLabels : {
                enabled : true,
                inside : false,
                style : {
                    color : "#000000",
                    fontWeight : "normal",
                    fontStyle : "normal",
                    textDecoration : "none",
                    fontFamily : "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                    fontSize : "11px"
                },
                formatter : function () {
                    return this.y + ""
                }
            },
            colorByPoint : true,
            zIndex : 1
        }
    ]
});});
```

Comment: Oops, just saw your comment and realized I had missed the y axis label.

Comment: Instead of using tickPositions, you can use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) and use loop to return all incremented ticks.

Answer (score 1):

For the bar labels, just add `allowOverlap: true,`, like so

```
 dataLabels : {
     allowOverlap: true,
     ...
```

Documentation reference - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.dataLabels.allowOverlap

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ezjm3dch/

---

For the y axis labels you'd have to reduce the xAxis font size, like so

```
xAxis : {
    ...
    labels : {
        ....
        style : {
            ...
            fontSize : "8px"
```

For larger font sizes, the axis label auto adjust making the intermediate ones disappear so as to avoid any overlap - I don't see any option to show

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jwu1b5jx/

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer but I would like the same thing for the yAxis Labels

Comment: Updated answer. Cheers!

Comment: As I said in my question "the number of categories is variable, so increase the heigh is not a solution", in the same way decrease the font-size is not really a solution for me. Thanks. I edit my question for an another trick.

Comment: But wouldn't your labels overlap then, like so - http://jsfiddle.net/o1gnv4ec/ (I reduced the chart height to show what would happen if you have more labels)?

Comment: I don't mind if my labels overlaps I just want to see all my labels. In my uses case, the labels do not overlaps or very little so it's not a problem

Comment: @B.Chaudron Highcharts prevents axis labels from overlapping. This can be changed by using tickPositioner. [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner), Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y4aoua4t/

Comment: @KacperMadej - that's neat. I didn't notice that. You might want to post that as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts prevents axis labels from overlapping. This can be changed by using `tickPositioner`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y4aoua4t

API reference for more info: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner